# Add CSRF token to hard coded Django form

Tags: python, django, jekyll, csrf

I am building a **static page with Jekyll** that has a hard coded form, I am sending the form data to a Django server, I am having trouble generating a `CSRF token`. The only way I could get the data to save to the database was if I used a static csrf token which is hacky and pointless.

**Is there a better way this can be done?**

This is what I want:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://djangoserver" >
    {% csrf_token %} <!-- Doesn't work in Jekyll -->
    <input type="text" name="name" required id="id_name" maxlength="100>
 </form>
```

But obviously Jekyll doesn't know what that token is, and the POST doesn't send it to the Django Server.

---

This works, but it is vulnerable and hacky, I need the same effect that actually generates a unique token every time.

```
<form method="POST" action="http://djangoserver" >
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value=" some long stuff" >
    <input type="text" name="name" required id="id_name" maxlength="100>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `{% csrf_token %}` won't work because it's a Django template tag. Hardcoding a `csrfmiddlewaretoken` wouldn't work either because this value change so to provide the security.

I had a similar issue on my blog which is Jekyll as well. On a contact page I added the normal HTML form with the `action` pointing to my Django backend. For this view, I removed the CSRF token verification using the `@csrf_exempt` decorator.

To avoid abuse, I added a Google Recaptcha verification.

See below an example:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
import requests  # http://docs.python-requests.org

@require_POST
@csrf_exempt
def ask(request):
    recaptcha_response = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
    data = {
        'secret': settings.GOOGLE_INVISIBLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
        'response': recaptcha_response
    }
    r = requests.post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', data=data)
    result = r.json()

    if result['success']:
        # process form...
    else:
        # invalid recaptcha
```

Comment: clever, didn't think of that

Answer (score 1):

If this is **not** on the same domain, I would recommend setting up [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

**If it is on the same domain**, then do what is recommended on the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#ajax): you can get the CSRF token with JavaScript (note that I've changed the function to be used without jQuery):

```
// WITHOUT jQuery
function getCookie (name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
```

Update the form (note the `id`):

```
<form id="name-form" method="POST" action="http://djangoserver" >
    <input type="text" name="name" required id="id_name" maxlength="100>
</form>
```

Add the csrftoken input:

```
var form = document.getElementById('name-form'),
    input = document.createElement('input');

input.name = "csrfmiddlewaretoken";
input.type = "hidden";
input.value = getCookie('csrftoken');
// ^ could be a different string depending on your settings.py file

form.appendChild(input);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: So the form is on one domain(GitHub pages) and the Django will be hosted on a separate host. I feel like the js approach is the simplest, is it possible for me to generate that token on one server and it be sent over to the Django, or would I have to make the api for that?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.  If it is possible, it's not a good idea.  What you should do in that case is read up on Django REST Framework, and use that to create an API for your django server.  Then you can accept requests from other domain names.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying is impossible, the only way to make Jekyll static pages somewhat dynamic is to use JavaScript.

You could implement what you want by making API in your Django that will create CSRF token and return it and then you can append it to your form. This way you will always have dynamic CSRF, however I don't recommend sending CSRF tokens across network as it is unsafe.